# How to search regex in a url-retrieve buffer?

Tags: regular-expressions, search, networking

I'm trying to implement a login system with emacs lisp, the login system has a hidden input field that's initially empty and is filled by a piece of javascript code when submitting.

I'm currently using url-retrieve to get the site and I'm stuck getting the value in the javescript code, since re-search-backward only applies on the current buffer, and switching to the temp buffer can cause a great mess.

How can I search the specific buffer opened by url-retrieve?

More annoyingly, url-retrieve does not open a named buffer.

Is there a good way for me to the value and, better, the cookies, from a site?

Edit: Here are some code that I'm working on:

```lisp
(defun cas-login-get-cas-lt (&rest rest)
  "Get the cas-lt value."
  (let* ((url-request-method "GET")
         (urlbase "https://example.com/login")
         (service (plist-get rest :service))
         (url (if service (concat urlbase "&service=" service)
                urlbase)))
    (url-retrieve url (lambda (status) (switch-to-buffer (current-buffer))))
    (re-search-backward "LT-[0-9a-f]*")
    (thing-at-point 'string)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t really know what you intend to do, so I don’t know if you are going about it the correct way. However, `url-retrieve` takes a callback that is called once the response comes back. That callback is called with the response in the current buffer. That callback can search the buffer in the usual ways, either with `re-search-forward` or by other means.

Comment: This is really useful, and I can now print the target value to the message buffer, but how can I get the return value of the callback? Or do I have to set a variable and set it in the callback?

Comment: You don’t get a return value from the callback. `url-retrieve` sends off the query and then returns immediately. Your code continues executing and probably returns whatever it returns well before the reply comes back from the server. Have the callback do whatever needs to be done to finish the job, or have it call a function which does so.

Comment: Or you can always use `url-retrieve-synchronously` if you'd prefer to deal with simpler (but blocking) behaviour.

Comment: I cannot really recommend that route. Blocking means it blocks everything until the response comes back, or the request times out. If the user’s internet isn’t working, it could be 30 seconds before Emacs responds to any event at all. If you do it synchronously, set the timeout _really_ low.